# php array converting child class with sha1

Tags: php, inheritance, associative-array, sha1

I have the following piece of code (example for the problem):

```
class A  {
public $x;
public $y;
public function __construct($x, $y) {
    $this->x = sha1($x);
    $this->y = $y;
}
public function __clone() {
    return new A($this->x, $this->y);
}
}

class B extends A {

public $z;
public function __construct($z, $parent_obj) {
    $this->z = $z;
    parent::__construct($parent_obj->x, $parent_obj->y);
}
public function doSomeThing() {
    $parent_a_array = (array) parent::__clone();
    $child_a_array = array_diff_assoc((array) $this, $parent_a_array);
    echo "Parent Array Printing :<br/>";
    foreach ($parent_a_array as $key => $value) {
        echo "Key: $key; Value: $value\n".'<br/>';
    }
    echo "Child Array Printing: <br/>";
    foreach ($child_a_array as $key => $value) {
        echo "Key: $key; Value: $value\n".'<br/>';
    }


}
}

$t = new B('C', new A("A", "B"));
$t->doSomeThing();
```

I get a little bit weird output, i expect to have x,y printable only in parent, while z printable only on child, but the output is

```
Parent Array Printing :
Key: x; Value: 726c6aeb8252ad589562fe2c7409d50c90a058aa
Key: y; Value: B
Child Array Printing:
Key: z; Value: C
Key: x; Value: bd605412133b28b10c5fa7a45fce29df67c18bd7
```

When I remove the call to sha1 function in class A contructor, the output seems to be fine.

```
Parent Array Printing :
Key: x; Value: A
Key: y; Value: B
Child Array Printing:
Key: z; Value: C
```

I'll be grateful if any one knows a solution for this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are hashing x twice when you are cloning it, hence the x in the instance of B has a different value than the one in the clone of its parent (A).

`$this->x = sha1($x)` then in the clone you have `new A($this->x, $this->y)` which in fact is `new A(sha1(x), $this->y)`. So you end up with this

```
t = {
   x: sha1('A'),
   y: 'B',
   z: 'C'
}
clone_of_t = {
   x: sha1(sha1('A')),
   y: 'B'
}
```

Comment: Very Clear explanation, Thank you, solved my problem.

Comment: @developer I did double encryption also on the page when I'm checking this, however you can remove the sha1 call on the constructor, and call it only on the clone function and it'll work fine